# Cucumber: how to add default tags AND append tags passed from command line to the default tags

Tags: selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

My Cucumber Options looks like this

```
@CucumberOptions(
    dryRun = false,
    plugin = {
            "pretty",
            "html:src/test/java/testresult/cucumber-report/index.html",
            "junit:src/test/java/testresult/cucumber-report/cucumber.xml",
            "json:src/test/java/testresult/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
            "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
            },
    features = { "src/test/java/features" }, 
    glue = { "Hooks","stepDefinitions" },
    tags = "not @ignore",
    monochrome = true
)
```

when I run from command line, I use
`mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@regression"`, all the regression scenarios are running including the `@ignore` scenarios

Is there any way, we can assign default tags AND append tags from Command Line to the CucumberOptions?

I dont want to pass **"and not @ignore"** everytime from command line.

Comment: Give some examples for this line - "Is there any way, we can assign default tags AND append tags from Command Line to the CucumberOptions?".   What are you expecting?

Comment: When ever I filter with tags from command line, @ignore scenarios should be filtered out automatically without passing "and not @ignore" every time. Because, I want to create many test suites with different tags(sanity, smoke, regressions etc.) AND don't want to add "and not @ignore" to every test suite. Is there any other way, I can do that?